# Loop through jList indices to remove items

Tags: java, jlist, selected, indices

i try to loop through indices of my selected items in a jList to remove them.

```
int[] indexoptio;
    indexoptio = this.list_optio.getSelectedIndices();

    for (int i=0; i<indexoptio.length ; i++) {
        this.optio.remove(indexoptio[i]);}
    this.list_optio.setModel(optio);
```

It works perfect except when i only have 2 items in my list. When i select both items it only removes one of them...

Comment: it seems like he removes only every 2nd item... o0

Comment: Do it in other way, means instead of deleting the items from `this.optio`, create a new jList copy all the items in the new list except of those which needs to be deleted. than assign the new jList `this.optio`.

This will always give consistent result.

Comment: But how do i copy every item into a new jList except those which are in the indexoptio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be because changing a datastructure while working on a set of indexes referring to it unchanged.  This is easier shown using an example.  Say you have a list `items` with 3 elements:

```
["item1", "item2", "item3"]
```

And you want to remove items 1 and 3, using your code above what you're actually doing is:

```
items.remove(0);
items.remove(2);
```

After the first removal, the list has become this:

```
["item2", "item3"]
```

See how `"item3"` is now at position 1 whereas previously it was at position 2?

Your list of selected indices refer to the original list of data, but after the first delete list has *changed*.

I think the following should work for you:

```
int[] indexoptio;
indexoptio = this.list_optio.getSelectedIndices();

for (int i=0 ; i<indexoptio.length ; i++) {
    this.optio.remove(indexoptio[i]-i);
}
this.list_optio.setModel(optio);
```

Every iteration the original list has decreased in size by 1 and some elements have shifted down, so by subtracting the loop counter (`indexoptio[i]-i`) it should keep the values in sync

Comment: No problem, I hit the exact same problem when I first started using Swing :)